# Universal covering space of a 'Lasso'-shapes space

Tags: algebraic-topology

I seem to have some basic confusion about universal covers that I can illustrate using an explicit example.

We were asked only to draw and explain briefly the universal covering space of

$$X=S^1\cup[1,2]$$
[image]

I first observed that the potential problematic point would be $1$ (or $(1,0)$ depending on how we view $S^1$). So, to try and work it out I know that $p:\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ given by $x\mapsto \exp(2\pi i x)$ promises us that $\mathbb{R}$ is the universal covering of $S^1$.

Now, $p(0)=1$ and $p$ is periodic of period $1$ so we can conclude that $p^{-1}(\{1\})=\mathbb{Z}$. Intuitively, that means that the covering space of $X$ would be the real line with some 'spikes' in any integral point. Since I think of universal covering as the best possible cover, in the sense that any other covering space maps is mapped into it uniquely (the universal property) I have some confusion about what should be the exact nature of these 'spikes'.

Would attaching an arbitrary closed interval of an arbitrary length to any integral point of the real line would be enough? (resulting in some comb-shaped space) Or should these 'spikes' be composed of an entire copy of the real line as well to ensure the ability to lift it?(resulting in some comb-shaped space to comb in infinitely long hair). The problem with taking $\mathbb{R}$ is that it is homeomorphic only to open intervals via some good parametrization of $\tan$, so I'm not sure it would do any good.

Since I was asked to draw and explain briefly only, I do not expect a formal, detailed answer, although that would be great, I simply feel I lack the intuitive grasp of how to decide between the spaces at this point and maybe a some hint if my construction was right at all.

Thank you!

Comment: If you attach copies of $\mathbb{R}$ as your spikes, what would be the preimage of $\{2\}$ in your universal cover?  (Also, what are you doing with the other end of $\mathbb{R}$?)

Comment: ughh yea you’re right https://math.stackexchange.com/users/50427/jhf ! this somewhat follows the comment on $\mathbb {R}$ and $\tan$ but gives the precise details of my concerns. so just to make sure i got everything right: we can attach closed interval of arbitrary length (the finite comb construction) and now the solution would be right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turning the discussion in the comments into an answer.

The universal cover of $X$ is given by $\mathbb{R}$ together with a closed bounded interval attached at one end to each point in $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$, e.g., $$\tilde{X} = \{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \{(n, y) \mid 0 \leq y \leq 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.$$  (Any other universal covering - e.g., changing the lengths of the spikes - is related to this one by a covering homeomorphism.)

We can see that it is not $$\{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \{(n, y) \mid y \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\},$$ since we would not be able to find an "endpoint" on each of the spikes to map to $2 \in X$.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! One last question about your remark "Any other universal covering - e.g., changing the lengths of the spikes - is related to this one by a covering homeomorphism."

This is essentially the idea that universal constructions are unique up to isomorphism? (As in isomorphism in the relevant category)

Comment: Yes, I think so.  More precisely, the universal cover covers any other connected cover of the base space, and the covering is unique up to Deck transformations.